# Nested query that will fetch latest row in grouped result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT * from `provider_info` where provnum not in 
 (select pi_provnum from prov_index where length(pi_provnum)=6)
 and length(provnum)=6 group by provnum
```

prov_index will only have one row per provnum/pi_provnum.  But provider_info can have multiple rows per provnum.

I'm basically pulling rows from one table that do not have an entry by provider (provnum/pi_provnum) in the second table.  The inner query gives me a list of provnum columns that exist in the provider_info table but do not exist in the prov_index table.   (the length() conditions are extra things I need in the query)

Since there may be multiple entries with the same provnum in provider_info, I use a 'group by provnum' clause to only give me one instance.  But I ultimately need all columns that correspond to the row with the latest 'sourcedate' value.

1. Is there a way to use DISTINCT instead of the GROUP clause?
2. Ultimately, I need to return one specific row (all columns) from provider_info, that is the row with the latest date in the column "soucedate"

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
 SELECT * from `provider_info` where provnum not in 
 (select pi_provnum from prov_index where length(pi_provnum)=6) 
 and length(provnum)=6 order by provnum,sourcedate desc group by provnum 
 having sourcedate=max(sourcedate)
```

Basically what I want is a list of one row from provider_info that has the latest sourcedate column where the provnum doesn't exist in the second table prov_index.   The key is I want all the columns in that last row, not simply a max(sourcedate)

Can this be done in a single complex query?

Comment: You might be able to use order by and limit for the filter...     Select * from provider_info order by sourcedate limit 1

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NOT EXISTS clause. It has a case where it could return duplicate lines, if you had two records for the same provnum in provider_info and the same sourcedate (being the latest date). If that's not possible in your scenario, or if you would want both rows in such case, this could work:

```
SELECT p1.* 
from `provider_info` p1 where p1.provnum not in 
(select pi_provnum from prov_index where length(pi_provnum)=6) 
and length(p1.provnum)=6
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM provider_info p2 where p1.provnum = p2.provnum AND p1.sourcedate > p2.sourcedate 
)
```

Sidenote, I would also replace the "*" with the actual list of fields you want the query to return.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to test this and report back!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the query like this:

```
 SELECT p.*
   FROM
        ( -- latest sourcedate for each provnum
          SELECT s.provnum
               , MAX(s.sourcedate) AS latest_sourcedate
            FROM `provider_info` s
           WHERE LENGTH(s.provnum) = 6
           GROUP
              BY s.provnum
        ) q

     -- row(s) that matches latest sourcedate
   JOIN `provider_info` p
     ON LENGTH(p.provnum) = 6
    AND p.provnum         = q.provnum
    AND p.sourcedate      = q.latest_sourcedate

     -- anti-join exclude rows that have a match
   LEFT
   JOIN prov_index i
     ON LENGTH(i.pi_provnum) = 6
    AMD i.pi_provnum = p.provnum
  WHERE i.pi_provnum IS NULL

  ORDER BY ...
```

Let's unpack that a bit.

Inline view (derived table) **`q`** gets us distinct values of `provnum` from `provider_info` with the the latest `sourcedate` for each.

We can join that result to `provider_info`, and get the rows that match on `provnum`, and have a `sourcedate` that matches the `latest_sourcedate`.

To get rows excluded, I'd prefer to use an anti-join pattern instead of a NOT IN. The way this works, we do an *outer* join to find matching rows from `prov_index`. The LEFT outer join will return all rows from the left side, along with matches from the right side. The trick is to use a condition in the `WHERE` clause that *excludes* rows that found a match. The join predicate guarantees us that matching rows will have a non-NULL value for `pi_provnum`. So if we exclude rows that have a non-NULL value i.e. only return rows that a NULL value for `pi_provnum`, what we have left is the rows from the LEFT side that didn't have a match.